# Conformal maps on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a domain bounded by a closed smooth curve,(i.e $\Gamma=\partial\Omega$),  $\mathbb{D}_+=\{z: |z|>1\}$ and $\Omega_+=\mathbb{C}\setminus{\Omega}$. Suppose $\phi_1:\mathbb{D}_+\rightarrow\Omega_+$ and  $\phi_2:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\Omega$ are corresponding conformal maps. Is that the case that derivatives of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ coincide on $\mathbb{T}=\{z:|z|=1\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Actually, $\phi_1^{-1} \circ \phi_2$ can be *any* orientation preserving smooth diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{T}$ onto itself. This follows from the so-called *conformal welding theorem*.

I'm curious : what made you think this could be true?